# Using Active Directory services with a Silverlight Browser Application

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, active-directory

I'm making a Web App with Silverlight for my company.

This app's aim is simple : let each user to manage his informations on the AD such as adress, city, phone, mail...

Because I'm friendly with WPF Desktop App, I want to do that with the same XAML and C#, so I choose to use Silverlight Browser App.

I've seen that I can't import System.DirectoryServices so I can't use common DirectoryEntry.

Please, can someone tell me exactly what to use and how to use AD with Silverlight app?

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight only has access to a small subset of the classes available in the full .NET Framework. Furthermore, the Silverlight application runs in a secure sandbox in the browser.

To do what you want, you must expose the data through a web service.

---

The easiest place for you to start is to look at RIA Services.